# Matching two sections same number of times

Tags: regex, preg-replace, pcre

I'm searching for code to parse the following:

some texttext

I need to remove unnecessary `<span>` occurrences, so that output is:

some texttext

I wrote a regex, which does this once:

/[^<]*</SPAN>/i

How do I make this work same number of times on both `<span>` and `</span>`?

Comment: For the nth time: regex is not for parsing HTML!

Comment: I don't think it can be done with regular expressions, I think the grammar is at least context-free.

Comment: @progo: More like "for the n^1000th time"…

Comment: @progo: maybe it's better to say: cleaning HTML rather than parsing. Anyone got better solution to cleaning HTML generated by Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '%(?<=<span>)        # Assert that there is a directly preceding span tag
    <span>               # Match a span tag
    ((?:(?!</?span>).)*) # Match the contents of the tag only if they do not include another span tag
    </span>              # Match a closing span tag
    (?=</span>)          # Assert that there is a directly following span tag
    %six', 
    '\1', $subject);
```

will work on your example, but it has to be applied twice because it removes one "layer" of nested `span` tags per iteration.

So, with arbitrarily nested tags, you'd need to call this once for each level of nesting.

Comment: Well, this looks like the answer I need. However, I get connection aborted error while testing this (I only added /i modifier, no other changes).

Comment: Hm, no idea what that error means. You did realize that in this regex, the delimiters are `%`, not `/` characters, so if you add a `/i`, you're introducing an error? I have now edited my regex to make it case-insensitive.

Comment: This is it, thank you. Looks like it breaks my windows server, however works on linux and in windows CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to see if a `<span>` is directly followed by another `<span>` *and* its matching `</span>` is directly prepended by another `</span>`.

But you cannot actually say that that span will be useless, because markup can be added to those specific spans. If there isn't any markup, the last remaining spans are useless as well and might just as well be removed too.